# Defining the zIndex of all objects in a class

Tags: javascript, z-index

I want to set the z-index of several elements in the dialog class to 1.

Currently I am using the code below:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("dialog")[0].style.zIndex = "1";
```

But surely only works for the first Element. Defining an array also doesn't work because I don't have a fixed number of objects in the class. Is there another way to fix this issue??

Comment: The answers below solve your problem but don't explicitly call it out - you have changed the first element of your array and ignored the rest.  With a for loop you can perform the action on each item in the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a loop:

```
var els = document.getElementsByClassName("dialog");

for (var i = 0, l = els.length; i < l; i++) {
   els[i].style.zIndex = 1;
}
```

And here's a fun piece on loop alternatives: http://htmlcssjavascript.com/javascript/another-front-end-engineer-interviewing-question-loop-alternatives/

Update: as pointed out in a comment, your code as written only affects the first element (index [0]). The method `getElementsByClassName` returns a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/NodeList) containing all the selected elements. You need to iterate over the list to update each element individually, hence the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to iterate through the elements of the array returned by getElementsByClassName() like so:

```
var a = document.getElementsByClassName("dialog");
for (var x = 0; x < a.length; x++) {
  a[x].style.zIndex = 1;
}
```

Comment: A `for` loop without braces is a dangerous practice.

Answer (score 1):

By using `[0]`, you're only selecting the first element.

I want to show you another way to loop through these elements.

```
var a = document.getElementsByClassName( 'dialog' ),
    forEach = Array.prototype.forEach.call.bind(Array.prototype.forEach)

forEach( a, function( el ) {
    el.style.zIndex = 1
} )
```